# Difference between Heap Cache and normal Cache

Tags: java, .net, esb

Can anyone explain what is the difference between Heap Cache and normal Cache? are both same regarding speed and high availability or there is any difference?

Comment: We cannot answer your question because it´s unclear what exactly you mean by "heap cache" or "normal cache", please clarify your question!

Comment: i have started learning an enterprise software suite in order to implement ESB for our organization.
in this architecture we are supposed to use Terracotta cache, which is based on EHCache( http://www.ehcache.org )
in Terracotta they say they use Heap Cahce so i am confused between the cache i have doing all the time normally and this new term Heap Cache. hope its clear now

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [ehCache documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/get-started/storage-options.html#bigmemory-(off-heap-store)). Java organizes most of its objects within a [heap structure](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html). This means when using an "heap cache", ehCache stores the data there.

Additionally there is an "off-heap cache", meaning some other structures and memory locations are used to store the data. This might be useful for bigger caches and a separation from the normal Java heap.